# JavaScript Internals: Where are the variables stored in-between compilation and execution phase ?

Tags: javascript

> Reference: You don't know JS (scopes & closures)
>
> Chapter 2: Lexical Scope

Consider an example:

```
var a = 2;
```

JavaScript first compiles the above code. So first the compiler does the lexical breakdown. It breaks it down as:

```
var a; &
a = ?;
```

While breaking it down as var a it informs the scope about it. And the scope maintains information that a is present within that scope or not.

Then begins the execution stage. Where a = 2 is assigned. I am trying to understand where the value of "a" i.e a = "2" stored before the execution stage starts i.e is there any memory allocation happening.

Comment: There's definitely memory allocation happening since it needs a place to store `a`. How exactly that's handled will vary based on the JS engine in question.

Comment: @MikeC then the question becomes whether the compiler itself stores the data in-memory. 

Another thing, where can I get this info ? Like internals of JavaScript...

Comment: Well, the *interpreter* will keep the value in memory, maybe somewhere on disk if needed. The *compiler* just provides an output. If you want to understand the internals of an engine, I'd suggest looking for the V8 source code.

Comment: thanks @MikeC appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not only do the lexical breakdown, it parses the whole code into an appropriate data structure (e.g. a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree)) that also holds literals such as `2`. It basically holds an instruction such as "In a scope with the variable `a`, assign the value derived from the constant expression `2` to the variable with the name `a`."

Comment: This is interesting ! So the compiler itself maintains the information as parse tree. Does that mean that the compiler stores the data in-memory i.e cache and after compilation does it clear that data. 

Just curious !!

Comment: No, it doesn't clear the data, that data is the very output of the compiler which the interpreter needs to execute code.